# How can i get different data?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax

JavaScript code:

```
$(function() {
        timer = setInterval( function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: "ip/img",
                type: "get",
                context : this,
                cache : false,
                error : function(request,status,error){
                    alert("code:"+request.status+"\n"+"message:"+request.responseText+"\n"+"error:"+error);
                },
                success:function(obj){
                    $("#imguri").html('<img src="'+obj.data+'">');
                    //$("#imguri").attr("src", obj.data);
                    console.log(obj.data);
                }
            });
            }, 3000);
        });
```

Print same data
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4IDd.png):

My server code:

```
client.on("message", async(topic, message)=>{ // {"LED" : "ON"} or {"MOTER" : "ON"}
    if(topic == "JPG")
    {
        var obj = message.toString();
        app.get("/img", function(req,res,next){
            res.set("content-Type", "text/json");
            res.send(JSON.stringify({data : obj}));
        });
        console.log(obj);
    }
}
```

Print different data:

How can I get a different value each time from http?

Comment: Please provide some context. `app.get("/img", ...)` usually isn't called multiple times, since it sets up a handler for the AJAX request. What is `client` in your code?

Comment: client is arduino module that is send image to server.

Comment: Ok, so each time the arduino sends a `message`, that `message` is now set back as reply to the AJAX request. Now please explain what you mean by "different data"? Do you mean like keeping a list of messages/images and sending back a random one?

Comment: i wanna render different temporary image each time on html. i'm not want to keeping list. different data is data uri

Comment: In that case your Arduino needs to send a new message more often. You will keep seeing the same image until the Arduino sends a new message with a new image.

Comment: Arduino sends a new image every 3 seconds. i check different data uri with print(obj). but in html, console.log is print same data uri

Comment: You need this: https://pastebin.com/7hJhWm7R